# Windows 10 Red Screen! (Important Updates Needed)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am receiving a red screen on my workstations as shown below. Is this for real, or just some sort of a virus or spam?

It is stating that my copy of Windows 10 will stop and I need to download a 6 GB update.

- I'm using Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Dell workstations and laptop.
- Using Kaspersky Endpoint Antivirus.

[image: Image here of the Warning sign]

Comment: So, make the decision either download the update and continue or don’t and suffer the possible consequences...

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you currently running?

Comment: 1500 Built , Thank you I will manage to update

Comment: If for some reason this update fails, simply hit not right now, then reboot, making it finish updates, and then when windows booted up, immediately after go to Settings -> Updates, and update from there.

Comment: @JonasCz It doesn't force anything. You can opt out (_Not right now_ button at the bottom), but you won't receive security updates. Same with Linux, it won't be secure forever if you don't update it.

Comment: @IanKemp: Have you considered... you know... *reading* the question and... seeing what it tells you? It literally asks *"Is this for real, or just some sort of a virus or spam?"* which is not something you discern just from the popup.

Comment: Interestingly I was presented same message twice but in less intimidating grey shade.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> #### It's stating that my copy of windows 10 will stop

Actually, it is telling you that your version on Windows will no longer be supported after April 10th, 2018.

You are presumably using an out of date version of Windows 10.

Windows 1511 will no longer be supported after 10.04.2018.

> Microsoft is planning to release its next Windows 10 update in April. The software giant hasn’t officially revealed its name, but the company is planning to label it the Spring Creators Update. Microsoft has, however, revealed the Spring Creators Update will be released in April. In an update to a blog post today, Microsoft provides a Windows 10 overview that includes the April release date, and plans to support the OS version until October 2019.
>
> [image]

Source [Windows 10’s Spring Creators Update will be available in April - The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/13/17114546/microsoft-windows-10-spring-creators-update-release-date)

See also [Another Windows 10 version overview – Red Pill BLOGS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hewagen/win10ver/) and [Windows lifecycle fact sheet - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74709/discussion-on-answer-by-davidpostill-windows-10-red-screen-important-updates-n).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update your Windows 10 and you're annoyed from the message every boot like me you can make it go away by uninstalling the windows update KB4091461.

> Windows Update Settings -> Update History -> Uninstall Updates -> KB4091461